# Using jacobian to transform area elements from one system to another.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral, change-of-variable, jacobian

Please excuse my lack of rigor,I'm just average Physics undergraduate.

I have a transformation from $(u, v)$ to $(x, y)$. So an infinitesimal area element from $ (u, v)$ to $(x, y)$ plane  will generally map as shown. [image]

Using Jacobian we relate these area elements as

$d A=J. d u .d v$

where
$d A \neq d x d y$.

So we can write for some $f(x, y)$ on a region

$\int f(x, y) d A=\int f(u, v) J d u d v$

But how does this follow

$\int f(x, y) d x d y=\int f(u, v) J d u d v$

Since we know that $d A \neq d x d y$ then why is $dA$ replaced by $dx dy$.
Every online source does it, replacing a parallelogram $dA$ by a square $dx.dy$.

I'd be grateful if someone helped. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you say "we know that $dA \neq dx \, dy$? Right above that you say $dA = J \, du \, dv$, but this is the same as $dx \, dy$, by the change-of-variable formula.

Comment: From the diagram we can see that the $dA$ is the area of a parallelogram and not of a square

Comment: In this scenario, $x$ and $y$ are not the independent variables (they depend on $u$ and $v$). So $dx \, dy$ is not the area of a square. $dx$ means a small change in $x$, which depends on a small change in both $u$ and $v$. So depending on how $u$ and $v$ change, the change in the $(x,y)$-plane might not be just a horizontal segment.

Comment: Exactly that's my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x = x(u,v)$ and $y=y(u,v)$ are functions of $u$ and $v$, you  can write their differentials using the standard formula:

$$ dx = x_u du + d_v dv \hspace{0.5cm} \text{ and } \hspace{0.5cm} dy = y_u du + y_v dv $$
I've used the subscript notation for partial derivatives, so $x_u$ means $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$, etc...

Now assuming $dA$ means $dx \, dy$ (which it usually does), you get
$$ dA = dx \, dy = x_u y_u du^2 + x_v y_v dv^2 + x_uy_v d_u d_v + x_v y_u dv du $$
The symbols "$dx$", "$dy$", "$du$", "$dv$", and "$dA$", are usually explained in low-level undergrad calculus courses as represented a "really small" length or area, as your picture indicates. But this is a convenient lie. They are really algebraic objects called "differential forms". See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) for more info.

The important part for this discussion is two properties of multiplication of differential forms.

1. If you square a differential form, you get $0$. So $du^2 = 0$ and $dv^2=0$.
2. It is not commutate, and $du \, dv \neq dv du$. In fact it is "anti-commutative" which means $dv du = - du dv$.

Applying these two rules to the equation above, you get

$$ dA = dx \, dy = (x_uy_v - x_vy_u) \, du \, dv = J \, du \, dv$$